# font family applied in iphone simulator but not appied in real iphone device?

Tags: css, iphone, cordova, fonts, telerik

My html page look like following :-

```
<div class="row">
   <p class="fonts"> am building a browser-based mobile app and I've decided    to use Bootstrap 3 as 
    the css framework for the design. Bootstrap 3 comes with a great "responsive" feature 
    in the navigation bar where it collapses automatically if it detects a specific "break 
    point" regarding the resolution of the browser. It works in a lot of situations</p>
</div>
```

My css look like following:-

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Calibri';
        src: url('../fonts/Calibri.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/Calibri.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../font/Calibri.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Calibri.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/Calibri.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }

.fonts {
        font-family: Calibri;
        -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1, dlig=1";
        -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga","dlig";
        -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga","dlig";
        -o-font-feature-settings: "liga","dlig";
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga","dlig";
        font-feature-settings: "liga","dlig";
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }
```

i am working with telerik app builder in visual studio and my directory structure of font is project_directory/fonts/...

Answer (score 1):

Try updating this so that it's in quotes:
    .fonts {
      font-family: 'Calibri';
    }

Comment: ok...thanks for ur response..by updating it will it works in real iphone device ?

Comment: You'll be able to tell me once you do it. At the moment without it, it is incorrect but sometimes browsers are forgiving and still work the way you want even when you use incorrectly formatted code.

Comment: Are you sure you've referenced the Calibri fonts/directory correctly? What device are you testing these on? Are you able to inspect the page to see if any assets aren't being loaded correctly? I am wondering if because 'Calibri' is a native font on most pc's, whether it is creating a false positive result on your simulator?

Comment: yeah i'd referenced it correctly..and currently i am testing it on iphone 4s,and i'd inspected the page in simulator and there is not any error that may affect the code or stop execution of code...

Comment: It's working in all the simulator(i mean mentioned device in telerik),real android,windows phone device but facing issue with real iphone device only...think it if by mistake i set path incorrect so it should not work in real android device too...isn't it ?

Comment: On your iPhone, which browser are you using - Safari or Chrome? And are the results the same across both? Do you have a different iPhone you can test it on, a 5 or a 6? The only other thing i can think of that might be causing the issue are the differences in browsers and which file type they use when referencing your fonts. http://www.stunningcss3.com/resources/fontface-file-types-browser-support.html You need to make sure that your IIS is serving all the different file types http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/

Comment: And one more thing to check, navigate to your fonts folder and open the '.svg' file in a text editor. Near the top of the code you should see a font tag with an id. Make sure that the id there is equal to what you have used in your font-face declaration in your css. check the hashtag matched the id. url('../fonts/Calibri.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');

Comment: Actually i'd developed web app and recently i'm testing it on iphone 4s,by the way don't worry i'd got the solution there was a problem with my path which was given like src: url('../fonts/Calibri.eot') and i'd tried to replace it with src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot') and works like charm in android and iphone as well...thanx :)

Comment: Was the fonts folder in the same folder as the css file?